# MR_importFromObject serialize nested array from JSON object

Tags: ios, json, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new to Core Data and interested how can I store data of JSON object with 'MagicalRecord' import i.e. there is JSON object and I store every field of this object with `mappedKeyName` using `userInfo`. But there is a problem with nested array inside my JSONObject.

JSON object look like:

```
{
"name" : "Some contact name",
"address": "Some contact address",
"phone": "123456789",
"email": "email@example.com",
"site": "http://example.com",
"detail_schedule" : {
  "week_days" : ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday"],
  "work_hours" : ["15:00 - 16:00","14:00 - 16:00","11:00 - 12:00", "10:00 - 12:00"]
  }
}
```

And the question is how to store `week_days` and `work_hours` of `detail_schedule` in my entity if entity has fields like "schedule1", "schedule2".. "time1", "time2", etc.
I need to store nested array like "schedule1" - "monday" (detail_schedule.week_days[0]). I've set `mappedKeyName` as `detail_schedule.week_days[0]` but have no luck.
I don't want to create another entity for example called `Schedule` because there is only one object with there nested arrays. How can I store their fields?

Comment: Did you try `detail_schedule["week_days"][0]`?

Comment: @Mundi I've tried yet. No luck again

Comment: I think you cannot use subscripts like `[0]`. You will have to work around this in code by setting these attributes "manually" via one of the import delegate callbacks.

Comment: I think you cannot use subscripts like `[0]`. You will have to work around this in code by setting these attributes "manually" via one of the import delegate callbacks.